Salesforce User with a certain profile can only delete contact base on Account.field__c and the user.field__c is the same
Salesforce User with a certain profile can only delete contact base on Account.field__c and the user.field__c is the same.
do you guys have any ideas on how to do this. I need the user to delete a record if the contact records Account.field__c is the same as the users field__c. I have tried a validation rule:
I also give the user's profile a delete access and modify all on the contact object.
AND(
OR(
$Profile.Name = "HA Customer Care - External/Agents",
$Profile.Name = "HA Customer Care - Internal"
),
TEXT($User.ps_BookingOfficeID__c) != Account.ps_BookingOffice__r.Name
)

this is a picklist $User.ps_BookingOfficeID__c

This can be achieved via either a Record Triggered Flow or an Apex Trigger. Generally, the recommendation is to utilise a Flow to reduce customisation so that is what I'll detail below.
To complete this, you'll need to create a Record Triggered Flow on the Contact object and ensure this is set to run 'When a record is deleted'. If you have criteria that will always skip this logic, then you can also add this as entry criteria so that they Flow never fires (and the records are always deleted).

Next the Flow will use a Decision Node to check if the field values match, using the Triggering Contact and the Running User resources as the Contact and User respectively.

If there is a match, the Flow will end. If there is a mis-match, then use a Custom Error node to throw an exception and inform the user that they can't delete these records.
Overall, this can be achieved with a Flow that looks like the following.

Just to add to your question though, unless your users don't have access to modify records based on Org Wide Defaults, I would recommend removing the Modify All permission as this is potentially a high risk permission to grant.
If you do want to use a Trigger, then a similar approach can be used but using the Trigger context variables to check the running user and the Accounts related to the Contact.
